# Responsive navigation for all devices

Tags: html

My `navbar` overlapping `navbrand` in which logo of company and name is mention.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" alt="Brand" src="assets/images/logo.png"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">        
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li id="active"><a  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="services.html">Events</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="process.html">Pages</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="about us.html">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Shop</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Cause</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Donate</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: Umm... yea... No code. No question. No answer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Faizan Rasool hi what is the problem .>??? from me it's working properly you might having issue with css for that

Comment: @Himesh Aadeshara yes i have an css issue .The number of list items are 9 and when the page is resize to the size of tablet it overlape the nav-brand .

Comment: @FaizanRasool still it's not overlaping dude  see updated https://jsfiddle.net/wn320tno/1/ jsfiddle

Comment: @Himesh Aadeshara Got it thanx very much buddy.

Comment: @FaizanRasool can you tell us what was the issue.?

Answer (score 0):

here is the jsfiddle working for me with the same code of your please check out demo

```html
<nav class="navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" alt="Brand" src="assets/images/logo.png"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">        
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li id="active"><a  href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="services.html">Events</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="process.html">Pages</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="about us.html">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Shop</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Cause</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Donate</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a  href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

[Working for me demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wn320tno/1/)